# Compute objective speech quality from Anritsu data

Tags: voice, autoregressive-model, adaptive-algorithms, quality-factor

I want to compute an objective speech quality however what I have right now is the Anritsu raw data (layer between the Base Station Controller and the Mobile Switching Center), this raw data does not contain the Noise power , the original signal power nor other needed data to deal with (Bit error rate , Frame error rate...). Is there any way to compute the speech quality MOS at the layer between BSC and MSC or I have to get data from a layer of low level.Thanks for support.

Comment: hey! Can you link us to a definition of "objective speech quality"?

Comment: What I mean by Objective is that without making reference to the client and ask him about the rate to give for a voice quality as in this case the value will be subjective ( based on emotions and feelings of the clients at the time when he is being asked  and not mathematics) here is a link if you like : [link](https://ecs.utdallas.edu/loizou/speech/obj_paper_jan08.pdf)

Comment: So, which of the A-D measure considered in that paper is what you want to compute? I'm totally unsure how the RF noise power would affect audio quality in a digital system?

Comment: Well my question is can I objectively compute the speech quality (like the E-model MOS does or other algorithms mentioned in the paper ) in the layer between the BSC and the Mobile switching centers. My problem is that I cannot get access to the radio data otherwise it will be easy for me to compute it since at radio level I have all needed parameters

Comment: I'm confused – the paper you've linked to above has nothing to do with radio data?

Comment: Please read this you will understand me better : [E-model mos for voice quality ](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com12/emodelv1/tut.htm)

Comment: No, sorry, G.107's E-Model tells me exactly nothing here. citing G.107: "*the E-model, that has proven
useful as a transmission planning tool for assessing the combined effects of variations in several
transmission parameters that affect the conversational 1 quality of 3.1 kHz handset telephon*": this is all about the quality of speech. Between BSC and MSC, error-corrected digital voice packets are exchanged. Their quality is set by the codec and its parameters, and you very rarely get packet drops these days. So, I don't know what you want to compute here?

Comment: The RF noise is irrelevant, unless you get dropped packets (the likelihood of bit-altered data is nearly zero – there's enough checksumming to avoid that). The delay is nothing you can see at that interface. Really confused.

Comment: I am working with eoAint and eoIucs raw data well I am not a telecom engineer but I am just wondering if it is feasible that I quantify the speech quality at that level. Well thanks anyway for the discussion.